# Can Sqlite be implemented on a linux based apache server?

Tags: linux, apache, sqlite, server

Can Sqlite be implemented on a linux based apache server not for the purpose of a mobile site? If yes, how? If not, whats the easiest server to set up?

Comment: What do you intend to access sqlite with?  php, python, java?  The integration is at the level of the web stack.

Comment: Currently using php.

Comment: How'd you find that?? Been searching for hours. Thanks!

Comment: Through the magic of google :).